# Using two Fragment librarys

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` class in one piece of my code.
In another one, I need to use `android.app.Fragment`.

```
 MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

In that part in getting the message saying it can't cast `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`.

I know if I import `android.app.Fragment` that error would be resolved, but I can't, because I alreay have `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: "I need to use android.support.v4.app.Fragment class in one piece of my code. In another one, I need to use android.app.Fragment." -- why? That's not possible within a single activity.

Comment: Because I'm using a navigation drawer activity. In the code generated automatically, I have this: fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position))
                        .commit();.

Comment: But I'm trying to use maps. So I need MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)  getFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.map).

Comment: "Because I'm using a navigation drawer activity" -- so? You can use `DrawerLayout` with native fragments or the backported fragments. "But I'm trying to use maps" -- so? MapsV2 offers both native and backported editions of its fragment classes. Pick whether you want to use the native fragments or the backported fragments, and then use those consistently with both `DrawerLayout` and MapsV2.

Comment: Ok. Would you help me? It's my first time doing it.

Comment: [Here are two sample apps using `DrawerLayout` with native fragments](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/NavDrawer). [Here are 18 sample apps using MapsV2](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2), where all but the `Sherlock` one use native fragments.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you use `Fragment` from the `android.support.v4.app` package, just type in the whole name (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) Once you do that, remove the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` import, and replace it with the import you want.